# Set cursor position on TextBox when Label is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have this custom control which acts as TextBox with background image. This control consists of UserControl with a background image, a TextBox placed on top of it and a Label as a child control for TextBox.
Labels text is always equal to TextBoxes text. So when you click on that label it focuses the TextbBox.

Below is a MouseClick event for this control:

```
Label_FolderNameBox.Text = TextBox_Name.Text

Private Sub Label_FolderNameBox_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Label_FolderNameBox.MouseClick
    BackgroundImage = My.Resources.box_large_focus
    Label_FolderNameBox.Hide()
    TextBox_Name.Focus()
    TextBox_Name.Select(TextBox_Name.Text.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

What I want to achieve:

I want to focus the IBeam cursor in the `TextBox_Name` in the same position where it was clicked on the `Label_FolderNameBox`.
As you can see with this line of code `TextBox_Name.Select(TextBox_Name.Text.Length, 0)` it always puts the cursor at the very end of the text.

Comment: May i question why you put a label in front of the textbox? If the text and the cursor position is always the same, where's the difference to only using a textbox?

Comment: @Breeze It's simple. TextBox doesn't support transparency while Label control does. Therefore using Label I manipulate the background images on MouseEnter, MouseLeave and MouseClick events. When you click it, it hides and brings up a solid color background for the TextBox control. It also ads ellipsis when text exceeds control boundaries.

Comment: Getting the text position of the click point in a label is almost impossible if you're using variable width fonts like Arial and still very difficult with fixed width font like Courier. You'd have to take account of the label margin, the font size, whether it is bold or italic etc. A lot or work I think.

Comment: @Darius47 did you take a look at `RichTextBox`? It seems to have a `BackgroundImage`-Property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.backgroundimage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx